# Auto generate meta description for all products on Reindex data

Tags: magento-1.9

Auto generate meta description for all products on Reindex data like this :Buy {product name} for Rs {price} at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for {publihser}

Comment: There is no need to do this every time you reindex. Instead you can do this on product save. Listen for the product save before event and set the meta data then. In this way things will be more efficient.

Comment: @Woolfie i create a module on catalog_product_save_before this working when save product but not working for imported product

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. How are you importing products?

Comment: @Woolfie using external extension  instead of magneto's default import

Comment: In that case you could write a module with a cron job that runs once in a while. This could them check the most recent product id, if new ones have arrived do the update as desired. You could store the last product id or do a query to find products created since last check.

Comment: You can also just write the attribute catalog_product_action and that way you do not need to actually load the product.

Comment: .. you could also change the template code so that the meta data is shown exactly as you wish. In that way you won't need cron jobs etc. Could be simplest.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to observe the `catalog_product_save_after` event. It's triggered after saving the product.

The observer would look something like

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function saveInventoryData($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $product->setMetaDescription(":Buy {$product->getName()} for Rs {$product->getPrice()} at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for {$product->getPublisher()}");

        $product->save();
        return $this;
    }
}
```